# WCF IIS Setup. Client cannot connect

Tags: wcf, iis

First, I'm fairly new to WCF and IIS.

I have created a WCF duplex service. It runs fine hosted in IIS on my Dev PC. I can create a service ref and all runs fine.

I then hosted it on my Win 2008 server in IIS. In IIS When I click the "Browse to 192.168.0.2:8020 (http)" link it opens the folder browse page. Clicking the Service.svc file shows me the service's WSDL page.

But clicking either WSDL link gives me a Not Found error. Also, the WSDL link has the server name instead of the IP address in it:

*http://MyServer:8020/Service.svc?wsdl*

If I change the server name in the provided WSDL link to my IP:
*http://192.168.0.2:8020/Service.svc?wsdl*

and put it in a browser, I then see the WSDL.

When I attempt to use the second link (with the IP address) in the client to add a Service Ref it appears to work. But when I run it I get

"You have tried to create a channel to a service that does not support .Net Framing. It is possible that you are encountering an HTTP endpoint."

**Note:** The server had not yet had IIS setup. I believe it's set up correctly after following the instructions [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/596287/Broadcasting-Events-with-a-Duplex-WCF-Service) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/blambert/archive/2009/02/13/enable-iis.aspx).

When I try to create the service ref in my dev PC pointing to http://192.168.0.2:8020/Service.svc?wsdl it appears to work, but the config now looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <netTcpBinding>
                <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IInfoGovService" />
            </netTcpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="net.tcp://192.168.0.2:8020/Service.svc" 
                      binding="netTcpBinding"
                      bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IInfoGovService" 
                      contract="InfoGovProxy.IInfoGovService"
                      name="NetTcpBinding_IInfoGovService">
                <identity>
                    <servicePrincipalName value="host/192.168.0.2" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

... and I get the above error.

At this point I'm not really sure what's wrong. I could use some help from someone with some experience here.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using NetTcpBinding and hosted it in IIS

You required to make some settings on iis and server machine like
enable protocol, start service Net.Pipe Listener adapter, Net.Tcp Listener adapter, Net.Tcp Port Sharing services

Comment: I followed all of this when I set it up, and again now. This time, adding the service reference in the client seems to wok ok, but I still get the same error when I run it

Comment: try changing your identity tag <identity>
                        <dns value="<servername>"/>
                    </identity> also i did not see mex endpoint added in config file add mex endpoint and servicemetadata